# android:onClick get the id of the clicked item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a list of posts with the autor name.
I want to know which author name had been clicked.

[image: example of the list of posts]

The layout :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="userClick"
    tools:text="User" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/user"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user"
    android:onClick="postClick"
    tools:text="Content" />
```

When an author name is clicked this function is called :

```
public void userClick(View v) {
    //Is it possible to know which author name had been clicked from here?
}
```

What is the correct method to identify on which author name the user had clicked.

**EDIT**

I've tryied the getId() method

```
public void userClick(View v) {
Log.d("userClick called :",String.valueOf(v.getId()));
}
```

It always return the same id even if I click on different users.

[image]

Comment: Get your item data via getAdapterPosition() in your onClick() and you are good to go.

Comment: I've tryied v.getAdapterPosition(). The getAdapterPosition() function is not available.

Comment: not v.getAdapterPosition() just getAdapterPosition() assuming you are using recyclerview

Comment: I'm not using recycleview

Comment: check this Url http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Comment: can you show us your adapter code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using listview, you can use the following:

```
String author ;
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
@Override 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
Textview user = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
author=user.getText().toString();
}
});
```

Update : 
Did you try that ?

```
public void userClick(View view){
TextView textview = (TextView) view;
author=textview.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is the RecyclerView.

And you can use

**RecyclerViewAdapter.class**

```
private View.OnClickListener globalClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int clickedPosition = (int) v.getTag();
                // do something with position
            }
        }
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder**

```
holder.itemView.setTag(position);
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(globalClickListener);
```

Also if you want to get **view id**,

```
private View.OnClickListener globalClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if(R.id.title == v.getId()){
             // Clicked child view (R.id.title which is implemented in XML)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem by implementing an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` and adding it to my `ListView`. The following solution works because both MyAdapter and MyListener have access to the `Activity`'s `posts` field.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Post> posts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        posts = new ArrayList<>();
        posts.add(new Post("author1", "title1"));
        posts.add(new Post("author1", "title2"));
        posts.add(new Post("author2", "title3"));
        posts.add(new Post("author3", "title4"));
        posts.add(new Post("author2", "title5"));
        posts.add(new Post("author1", "title6"));
        posts.add(new Post("author3", "title7"));
        posts.add(new Post("author3", "title8"));

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new MyListener());
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return (posts != null) ? posts.size() : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Post getItem(int position) {
            return posts.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false);
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            if (holder == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            Post item = getItem(position);
            holder.user.setText(item.user);
            holder.title.setText(item.title);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private class MyListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Post item = posts.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.user, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        private final TextView user;
        private final TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            this.user = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user);
            this.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }

    private static class Post {

        private final String user;
        private final String title;

        public Post(String user, String title) {
            this.user = user;
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the java file, after calling the onClickListener, try to access the button or clickable using the `this` keyword. It refers the the context of the clicked item.
Works in Java and JavaScript.